# ac3 encoders any free or poor man priced ones?

Tags: ac3

I have just finished my first surround mix and after supplying the 6 channels for a DCP creation I was asked to create ac3 files to use on a dvd.  Nuendo 5.5 does not offer this as an export option.  From research it looks like I need pretty expensive software for that,  anyone have any price friendly or free options that could work,  I would really hate to just supply a stereo mix because that is the only thing that the dvd creation software I think will allow without already encoded audio.

Comment: I hope I don't sound like a complete idiot but what's the difference with encoding AC-3 with something like MediaCoder than using a paid application, is it illegal or something?

Comment: I believe it has to do with algorithm and software licensing from Dolby patents, hence the notations about generating a Dolby print with a Dolby-licensed encoder.  It could end up being a legal problem, if not a quality control problem.  Likely comes back to why LtRt encoders aren't free (the only two I know of are Dolby Surround Tools and Neyrinck, both of which are Dolby-licensed tools and cost a bit of money).

Comment: Just because a program wraps/encodes a file in AC3 (free) doesn't necessarily mean it adheres to the the strict compression standard, file data structure, and metadata schemes of Dolby's AC3 (licensed/paid) 

Answer (score 1):

Compressor can output an ac3 (stereo or up to 7.1) for $50, which I think is absolutely worth it.  Much cheaper than Dolby Media Encoder SE ($595).

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the Mac OSX Application "Compressor" is fantastic for ac3 encoding. Hoping you have a mac.

Comment: Nope, windows based